# PIG Script to split large txt file into parts based on specified word

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am trying to build a pig script that takes in a textbook file and divides it into chapters and then compares the words in each chapter and returns only words that show up in all chapters and counts them.  The chapters are Delimited fairly easily by CHAPTER - X.

Here's what I have so far:

```
lines = LOAD '../../Alice.txt' AS (line:chararray);
lineswithoutspecchars = FOREACH lines GENERATE REPLACE(line,'([^a-zA-Z\\s]+)','') as line; 
words = FOREACH lineswithoutspecchars GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;
grouped = GROUP words BY word;
wordcount = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, COUNT(words);
DUMP wordcount;
```

Sorry that this question is probably way too simple compared to what I normally ask on stackoverflow and I googled around for it but perhaps I am not using the correct keywords.  I am brand new to PIG and trying to learn it for a new job assignment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit lengthy but you will get the result. You could cut down unnecessary relations based on your file though. Provided appropriate comments in teh script.

Input File:

```
Pig does not know whether integer values in baseball are stored as ASCII strings, Java
serialized values, binary-coded decimal, or some other format. So it asks the load func-
tion, because it is that function’s responsibility to cast bytearrays to other types. In
general this works nicely, but it does lead to a few corner cases where Pig does not know
how to cast a bytearray. In particular, if a UDF returns a bytearray, Pig will not know
how to perform casts on it because that bytearray is not generated by a load function.
CHAPTER - X
In a strongly typed computer language (e.g., Java), the user must declare up front the
type for all variables. In weakly typed languages (e.g., Perl), variables can take on values
of different type and adapt as the occasion demands.
CHAPTER - X
In this example, remember we are pretending that the values for base_on_balls and
ibbs turn out to be represented as integers internally (that is, the load function con-
structed them as integers). If Pig were weakly typed, the output of unintended would
be records with one field typed as an integer. As it is, Pig will output records with one
field typed as a double. Pig will make a guess and then do its best to massage the data
into the types it guessed.
```

Pig Script:

```
A = LOAD 'file' as (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'([^a-zA-Z\\s]+)','') as line; 
//we need to split on CHAPTER X but the above load function would give us a tuple for each newline. so
group everything and convert that bag to string which will give a single tuple with _ as delimiter.
C = GROUP B ALL; 
D = FOREACH C GENERATE BagToString(B) as (line:chararray); 
//now we dont have any commas so convert our delimiter CHAPTER X to comma. We do this becuase if we pass this
to TOKENIZE it would split that into separarte column that would be useful to RANK it.
E = FOREACH D GENERATE REPLACE(line,'_CHAPTER  X_',',') AS (line:chararray);
F = FOREACH E GENERATE REPLACE(line,'_',' ') AS (line:chararray); //remove the delimiter created by BagToString
//create separate columns
G = FOREACH F GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line,',')) AS (line:chararray);
//we need to rank each chapter so that would be easy when you are doing the count of each word.
H = RANK G;
J = FOREACH H GENERATE rank_G,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as (line:chararray);
J1 = GROUP J BY (rank_G, line);
J2 = FOREACH J1 GENERATE COUNT(J) AS (cnt:long),FLATTEN(group.line) as (word:chararray),FLATTEN(group.rank_G) as (rnk:long); 
//So J2 result will not have duplicate word within each chapter now.
//So if we group it by word and then filter teh count of that by 2 we are sure that the word is present in all chapters.
J3 = GROUP J2 BY word;
J4 = FOREACH J3 GENERATE SUM(J2.cnt) AS (sumval:long),COUNT(J2) as (cnt:long),FLATTEN(group) as (word:chararray);
J5 = FILTER J4 BY cnt > 2;
J6 = FOREACH J5 GENERATE word,sumval;
dump J6;
//result in order word,count across chapters
```

Output:

```
(a,8)
(In,5)
(as,6)
(the,9)
(values,4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very very concise answer.  This taught me a ton of new techniques in PIG and I was able to expand on the solution a bit more to do some additional things with it and learn more.  Thanks again.